# Linking to index entries outside of the index

Tags: hyperref, indexing, bookmarks

I use the splitindex-option for imakeidx for multiple indices, but I decided to organize my index entries additionally another way in a table. Since I am keeping my indices, I was wondering if there is a easy way to reference the index entries with hyperref, without manually labeling (with the bookmark command I assume) every target location again.

My question is, is there a way to use `\ref`, `\nameref` or similar commands to reference the target of an already created index entry, even when using multiple named indices?